# sql server insert missing record

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is a `siteOrder` table where i am checking orders placed by sites in current week, two columns in question are `siteName` and `OrderDate`, i am only considering four sites and ignoring others.

But if there is no order placed for any of these four sites then i want `0` to be displayed against the site rather than no rows displayed, here is my solution

```
SELECT SiteName,COUNT(SiteName) AS Completed FROM SiteOrder WHERE SiteName IN ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4')
and DATEPART(mm,OrderDate) = DATEPART(mm,getdate())
and DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate) = DATEPART(yyyy,getdate())
and DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) > DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), getdate()))
GROUP BY SiteName
order by SiteName
```

that gives me

```
SiteName    Completed 
-----------------------
Site1               1
Site2               1
Site3               1
```

notice that site 4 is missing i want that to be showing 0 against site 4 rather then not displaying anything at all

Comment: Issue is in you Where clause. You have kept conditions of OrderDate column. If no record is there for Site4 it will be excluded. I have given solution below.

Comment: @AK47 - What if there are no orders *at all* in `SiteOrders` for one of those sites?

Comment: @AK47 - um, no. If there are no rows, at all (not just given the date criteria), for that site, that site can't possibly exist in your result set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  SiteName
    ,SUM(Case When DATEPART(mm,OrderDate) = DATEPART(mm,getdate())
                        and DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate) = DATEPART(yyyy,getdate())
                        and DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) > DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()), getdate()))
              Then 1
            Else 0 
            End) as Orders
from SiteOrder where SiteName in ('Site1','Site2','Site3','Site4')
GROUP BY SiteName
order by SiteName
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already have these values in another table, you can create four rows in a subquery and then use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT SiteName,COUNT(SiteName) AS Completed
FROM (
  select 'Site1' union all
  select 'Site2' union all
  select 'Site3' union all
  select 'Site4'
) Sites (name)
LEFT JOIN
    SiteOrder ON SiteName = Sites.name
WHERE
OrderDate > DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,0,getdate()),-1)
GROUP BY SiteName
order by SiteName
```

I've also tried to come up with an alternative expression for the `OrderDate` comparison. I believe that you just want that the `OrderDate` should be greater then the date of the previous Sunday (on a Sunday, the previous Sunday being taken as that same day)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try running just this part of the query...

```
SELECT SiteName 
FROM SiteOrder
```

This should show you all your sites.

Ensure that Site4 doesn't have any leading or trailing spaces in it's name, as that will confuse the in statement.

EDIT: I think I misread our question, you might be able to add the line by using an if statement, so if a site exists but is not in that criteria, then display it with 0